# ASP.NET MVC - Using Check Boxes to Update Many to Many Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am in a MVC project and am currently stuck with many-to-many mapping.

I have a many to many relationship. It models a student course selection in a university. A student has subjects and for the given semester there is a complete list of subjects.

Need: make a form that a student could visit the page and through the use of check boxes to select some subjects.

I created a View Modle (at least that is what I call it). It is the model that will be used in the View 'Edit'.

Edit.cshtml

```
//in the Edit View
@model StudentViewModel

//Some more code
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Std.Name)
//etc..
```

The student view model

```
class StudentViewModel
{
public Student Std { get; set; }
public List<SubjectsSelection> Subs{ get; set; }
}

class SubjectSelection
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public int ID { get; set; }
public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to add a set of check-boxes for each and every subject such that `Selected = true` will be checked.

I was planning to create a list of check-boxes through a `for` loop manually.

Can I do this with some thing similar for `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subs)` such that when the form is submitted I can use a controller like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Machine machine, SubjectSelection[] subs)
{
//Some code here
}
```

So that there after I will be able to make the necessary connections (at least hopefully) and save to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sample To show How you can Post Data to the controller Method*

**Razor Code:**

```
<div id="form">
        <table width="600">
            <tr>
                <td>Select Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="txtDate" type="date" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Expense Type:</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="ExpenseType">
                        <optgroup label="Room">
                            <option>Room Fare</option>
                        </optgroup>

                        <optgroup label="Mess">
                            <option>Monthly Mess</option>
                        </optgroup>

                        <optgroup label="Others">
                            <option>Bus Fare</option>
                            <option>Tapari</option>
                            <option>Mobile Recharge</option>
                            <option>Auto</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Cost:</td>
                <td>
                    <input  class="cost" type="text" size="45" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Extra Details:</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="extra" type="text" size="45" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <button href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="saveExpense();" >Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<script>
function saveExpense()
    {
        var expenseobject = {          //MyModel Expense has these fields
            date:$('.txtDate').val() ,
            type:$('.ExpenseType').val() ,
            cost: $('.cost').val(),
            extra:$('.extra').val()

        };

        $.ajax({
            url: './saveexpense',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ obj: expenseobject }),
            success: function (result) {
                handleData(result);

            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult SaveExpense(Expense obj)
        {
            obj.ExpenseId = Guid.NewGuid();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.expenses.Add(obj);
                context.SaveChanges();
                int total=context.expenses.Sum(x => x.cost);
                return Json(new {spent=total,status="Saved" });

            }
            else
                return Json(new { status="Error"});   
        }
```

Instead of making the object of the `Model` you can do the following:

You can directly `serialize()` the form using jquery and post the data to the controller...and you are done

Comment: I am actually very new to ASP.NET, could you give me a little more information.

Comment: It took me couple days to understand this approach! Thanks for the info!